# How to disable logging in nginx on root only?

Tags: nginx

I would like to store access logs for any uri other than "/" for a particular server. However, due to frequent pings on the root uri, I wan't to disable logging for that uri. I'm using nginx 1.10.3. Relevant configuration is:

```
http {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}

server {
    access_log off;
    location ~ ^/$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_com_access.log combined;
    }
}
```

I have tried several configurations of access_log parameters. For example,

- turning logging on for the server and off for the location
- Using different methods to match the location (i.e. =, ~, (none), etc.)

Everything I've tried seems to either log every request or log no requests for the server. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: I've also tried the if=condition parameter for the access_log in multiple configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://nginx.org/r/access_log, you can, in fact, use the `access_log` directive within an `if` statement within a location.  Additionally, you can use an `if` condition parameter directly within the `access_log` directive starting with nginx 1.7.0.

The best way to accomplish this might be to use a `map` and an `if` parameter of `access_log` in nginx 1.7.0 and newer:

```
map $uri $loggable {
    /  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

Otherwise, based on your config, it might be the case that you're using the assumption that multiple `location` directives can apply to a given request, which isn't the case — only a single `location` can match a given request.

The best way would thus be:

```
location = / { access_log off; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http {
    access_log off;
}

server {
    location ~ ^/$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_com_access.log combined;
    }
}
```

It will only log requests for `location ~^/$` and will imply that you will need to add the access_log per `location` or `server` block

Other option could be:

```
http {
    access_log on;
}

server {
    access_log off;

    location ~ ^/$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_com_access.log combined;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to keep the access_log on the http block as a default for server blocks without further access_log configurations. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you tried `access_log off` in the `server` block only for the domain you would like not to have logs for root, that way you may continue having `access_log on` on the `http` block but disable partially logs at a server block level